# What is standard date time string format for SQL query for insering data in datetime columns?

Tags: sql

Today I faced a problem while porting an SQL server database to H2DB. The SQL queries I had written to insert date time, wasn't working on H2DB. i.e '26-Jun-2019 01:00:00' gave exception on H2DB. My question is what is standard format for inserting date time which is database independent?

Comment: Try:   "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS".

Comment: What was the exception thrown?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Exception - [22007][22007] Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "01-Jun-2019 00:00:00"; SQL statement: UPDATE EM_SCHEDULER_CONTROLLER_POLLS SET PREFERRED_DATE_TIME='01-Jun-2019 00:00:00' [22007-196] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Jun"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard format as defined by the SQL standard is the ISO format, prefixed with the keyword `DATE`, e.g.

```
DATE '2019-06-26'
```

or for a timestamp:

```
TIMESTAMP '2019-06-26 17:42:00'
```

However not all database products support the SQL standard in that regard, so you will most probably not find one single format that will work across all database products.